# Destruction of object in local scope

Tags: c++, destructor

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
void foo() {  
 {
    myclass object;
    object.do_something();
 }
 cout<<"hello"<<endl;
}
```

Is `~myclass()` **guaranteed** to be called **by the time the local scope is exited**, or might it be called at a later time (such as when the function returns)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed:

> **[class.dtor]** Destructors are invoked implicitly for ... a constructed object with automatic storage duration when the block in which the object is created exits.