# What is the purpose of {} without any keyword before?

Tags: c++, c++11

Today, i spent 4 hours debugging a little mistake:

```
while (++i < nb); //Notice this semicolon that i put by mistake
{
    do_stuff();
}
```

I didn't know why the do_stuff didn't execute enough times.
When I saw my mistake, I wondered: Why the hell would someone enclose codes into braces in the middle of a function??
Can someone have an explanation? Is that the way C languages evolved ? (I know the BNF of C contains some weird things due to retro compatibility reasons)
And do you think pre incrementation in a loop is a bad thing, that I should write like above instead?

```
while (i < nb)
{
    do_stuff();
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: You have accidentally introduced a limited local scope.

Comment: It introduces a local scope, which could be used to [control destruction of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927795/destruction-of-object-in-local-scope).

Comment: In C, everywhere you can put a statement you can put a block instead (i.e. a list of zero or more statements enclosed in `{` and `}`. It happens that the semicolon you put by mistake after the `while()` condition is an empty statement that moves the block that encloses `do_stuff()` outside the loop.

Comment: @axiac:  This is not true:  In the statement `for(statement; statement; statement)` you ***cannot*** replace those statements with blocks.  Same thing with `switch(statement)`, `if(statement)`, etc.

Comment: I understood it introduced a local scope... The question was :What is the purpose of a local scope?

Comment: @abelenky These are not statements (in the grammar sense), they're *condition*s, or an *expression*, or a *for-init-statement*.

Comment: How about `printf("%s", statement);`?

Comment: There are many uses.  The biggest is to help with scope and local object destruction.  I find that I use a local scope like this very, very seldom.  However, it does have its uses.

Comment: @abelenky it seems you mistake statement for expression. Take a look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements and here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions ; it can help you identify them correctly.

Comment: @axiac:  From the reference you cited: `There are five types of statements: ... 3) selection statements, 4) iteration statements`.  Those describe ***exactly*** what I'm talking about. If you wanted to say any ***expression statement*** may be replaced by a block (aka compound statement), I might agree.

Comment: @abelenky (I quote from the same page, on the section **"Compound statements"**): *"The compound statement allows a set of declarations and statements to be grouped into one unit that can be used anywhere a single statement is expected."*

Comment: @abelenky it's not `for (statement; statement statement)`. It's `for (init_clause; cond_expression; iteration_expression) loop_statement` where `init_clause` may be an expression or a declaration. As for `loop_statement`, it can be any statement, including the null statement (`;` only), a block or any of the other types of statements described in the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to put all the logic inside the while and omit body intentionally. Some compilers will warn you about that, ie. clang:

```
main.cpp:18:17: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
while (++i < nb); //Notice this semicolon that i put by mistake
                ^
main.cpp:18:17: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
```

Introducing of local scopes like:

```
{
   SomeClass aa;
   // some logic
}
```

is also not uncommon, you might want, in above someone might want aa destructor to be called before the closing braces - ie. it will release some resource.

Comment: I never saw local scope in a middle of a function, that's why I wondered why it was possible without warning or something, but apparently clang do^^. Since I try to do some clear functions, I try to do them quite short and then it has poor meaning introducing a local scope. Thank you for the answer (and thanks to those who just answered "you introduced a local scope", but if you read my question you see that i understood that...)

Answer (score 6):

> Why the hell would someone enclose codes into braces in the middle of a function??

Thats not a strange think at all, but it introduces a scope, as in the following example:

```
void foo () {
    int a;
    {          // start a new scope
        int b = 1;
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }         // end of scope, i.e. b is out of scope now
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // error: unknown variable b !!
    double b = 0.0;              // just fine: declares a new variable
}
```

You can use it to localize the accessability of variables inside functions. In the example `b` is a temporary and by putting its declaration inside a local scope I avoid spamming the function scope with variable names.

Answer (score 5):

I believe most common use is together with RAII:

```
{
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
   // code inside block is under mutex lock
}
// here mutex is released
```

Comment: I was wondering, why no answer bothered to give a real example of where you'd want to use a local scope. It would be even better if there were a few words on why the local scope is useful with RAII.

Answer (score 1):

Local scopes make sense to limit the life time and scope of objects. They are vital to `switch`/`case` statements:

```
switch (i){
case 1:
    std::string s;
case 2:
    //does s exist or not? depends on the value of i
}
```

C++ says this is straight-up illegal. To fix this you introduce a local scope:

```
switch (i){
case 1:
{
    std::string s;
}//the lifetime of s ends here
case 2:
    //s is inaccessible
}
```

Now `s` is limited to its scope and you solved the problem of `s` being sometimes defined.

You can add as many local blocks as you want, for example this is fine:

```
int main(){{{{{{{{{{
}}}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{<statement>*}` (* means zero or more) are code blocks in C/C++ and are treated as a single statement.
Statements are things like `if (<expression>) <statement>` (note: this is a recursive statement).
Another statement could be `<expression>;`.

Also `{}` generates a new scope.

This is also the reason why you can give multiple statements in an `if` statement.

If it helps, you can think of them as inline functions, with access to the current scope. (Not a correct way to view it, but close enough)

Look at @tobi303's answer for an example.